# Active Admin requires restart of server for every change I make

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

I started using active admin and I love it!

However, for every change I do in the code I need to restart the server. Is that normal? 
I am in development mode and I have

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

in development.rb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this was a bug in Active Admin 0.3.3. We just released 0.3.4 which should solve the issue. Active Admin now reloads your files when you change them.

Comment: but what if I want to reload on every request?. My scopes are not working when a new associated record created or deleted until I make any change in register file. Any thought @Greg?

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes.
```

Whenever you made any changes in your plugin, environment.rb......
Be sure to restart your server when you modify.

For development environment you don't need to restart your server only when you modify code written in app, public

Comment: Yes, I am making changes in app. So do I understand correctly that there is no way around restarting the server every time I make such changes? Or is it a caching issue?

Comment: Sorry, I reread your answer. At first I had understood that you meant that any changes under app require a restart. But appearantly you meant the opposite. Strangely enough I do need to restart for every change under app. Could there be anything that I overlooked i the settings? Thanks for you help!

Comment: After experimenting some more, I understand that changes under app/admin seem to require a restart, but other changes under app don't. Now that I work mostly with partials, I don't need to restart as often.